# How to remove last character in Bash?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I am having problems removing the last character. I have this command:

```
df -h | awk 'NR>1 {print$1,$2,$3,$4}'
```

which yields:

```
directoryname1 40K 0 9.0G
directoryname2 90K 5.0M 78G
directorynamen 0 62M 70G
```

I found out that I could remove the letters (K,M,G) by using `+0`

this command:

```
df -h | awk 'NR>1 {print$3+0}'
```

yields:

```
0
5.0
62
```

how do I get the same result as the first command I have without the K,M,G?

Comment: It is working to me with `{$4=$4+0; print$1,$2,$3,$4}`

Comment: Why would you want to strip the units when using `-h`? You will never know what the numbers mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have self answered your own question:

```
df -h | awk 'NR>1 {print$1,$2+0,$3+0,$4+0}'
```

It works because strings are numeric, for non numeric strings:

```
df -h | awk 'NR>1 {print$1,substr($2,1,length($2)-1),
                           substr($3,1,length($3)-1),
                           substr($4,1,length($4)-1)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm with [@AdrianFrühwirth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379476/how-to-remove-last-character-in-bash/22379877#comment34020268_22379476) - Why would you want to do that? Or rather, [what are you trying to do?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

If you're trying to get all the `df` numbers with the *same* unit and without the unit in the output, simply use `df` without `-h` to get the number of **bytes**. If you want KiB, MiB, GiB or some other measure, you can use `-BK`, `-BM` or `-BG`, respectively, or see the `SIZE` format information in `man df`.